# Images not found on devices

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic/cordova app I am building. When developing in the browser I have no issues but when I build and run on devices or emulators they can't find my images. I have verified that the images are getting copied over to the platform projects, but do I have to do something special to be able to use them? For android, they are getting copied into `assets/www/images` and I am trying to reference them in my css using something like:

```
.myImage{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url('/images/my_image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

but in the console I get a `404 Not Found` error on both ios and android. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What I usually do is keep the images in the app's www/img folder and reference them from there :)

Comment: Well that's what I'm doing, only my folder is called `images` rather than `img`.

Comment: Have you tried using "img" instead? it might mess up cordova's structure.

Comment: I will try that. I setup the project using ionic and it created `images` automatically.

Comment: Tried that, breaks browser and still doesn't work on devices.

Comment: @ClaudiuS I tried recreating the project and the updated project template uses `img` now. Still didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
background: url('./img/my_image.png') no-repeat;
```

Comment: Works for iOS/"Other Devices" as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So I'm actually not sure why it does this, but the app root is not `www` like you would expect. After inspecting things with chrome's remote debugging, I found the root of the app was `android_www`. The reason it couldn't find my image is because according to the app, the location was `android_www/www/img/my_image.png`. By using relative pathing, I was able to load the image. The css looked like this (my css folder was a sibling to my img folder):

```
background: url('../img/my_image.png') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of /images/my_image.png
try images/my_image.png with out / it works for me

Comment: most elegant and simple solution

Answer (score 0):

What is working for me both when running off the local ionic serve or from the content of www copied to my web host is to use relative notation
../assets/img/
like so

```
.AMSView-background {
  background: url(../assets/img/UMSViewBGTile.png)  center center fixed;
  background-size: 50px;
  background-repeat: repeat;

}
```

I just did a ionic run android --prod
and the above relative specification **fixed the issue** as well on Android.

I have never built for iOS so I can't comment there.

Note: the above ../assets/img/ is working from my .scss files which I believe are getting compiled into build/main.css, thus it explains why we have to up one parent.

However, my reference from html which from my observation also gets transpiled into main.js using

```
../assets/img
```

but forcing current folder like so

```
./assets/img
```

as in

```
    <button ion-button (click)="AMSController.Loop()"> <img src="./assets/img/PC_LOOP.png" width="30px" height="30px"/> </button>
</div>
```

works in 2 areas, on local ionic serve and anywhere installed on my web host.  I can't explain why it works.

However it does not work on Android.

Perhaps someone can show me how to convert the image nested above inside an ion-button but from a .css so that I can take advantage of the '../assets/img/" path specification which is already working in 3 cases

1. Local
2. Hosted on my web folder
3. Android

Don't forget to accept the answer if works for you.
Thank you.

**UPDATE: I have a fix for Android as well**.

1. Using nothing as in "assets/img/PC_Loop.png"
2. Pay attention to your filename extension case PC_Loop.png and not PC_LOOP.png. I happen to host on Windows which does not care, but Android is a stupid Unix machine.  So on Unix hosting you also observe issue with casing.

I dislike very much anything case-sensitive, including sensitive programmers :), but I like case aware environments (language, OS, ...)

So why use nothing from .HTML and "../" from .CSS is totally absurd.

Hope this helps the next person.